# Get Facebook friend list in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a latest Facebook SDK 3.23.0([Download Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads)).In this SDK, many sample app source codes are available. I just run **FriendPickerSample**. In this tutorial after replacing  my  app_id.

When i run this sample code , i could not get friend list display. But i had run it in my friends phone & then after i got friendsList. Here only friends install this app friend list display.

I want to get all friends list. How can i achieve this?

I also try using Graph API.

My Code below.

```
public void facebooklogin(){
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
      @Override
      public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                  new Request(
                            session,
                            "/me/friends",
                            null,
                            HttpMethod.GET,
                            new Request.Callback() {
                                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    Log.e("OUTPUT", ""+response.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        ).executeAsync();
              }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }
      }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I am getting this type of output.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can't get all friends anymore!

Comment: But i have one app Birthday Reminder. In this app my all friend list display. @Tobi

Comment: Read the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions For new apps it's no longer possible, for v1.0 it will stop working an April 30th 2015.

Comment: So, this app birthday reminder stop working after 30th April 2015?@Tobi

Comment: Yes, it will if it uses the `friends_birhtday` permission.

Comment: Okay. I have one doubt. Candy Crush Saga game in getting friend list. Send friends to moves, gifts etc. So How it is possible? It also stop working? @Tobi

Comment: Read what I wrote... v1.0 can be used until April 30th 2015. After that, it will stop working to get the full friend list, only those which are using the same app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70551/discussion-between-jigar-shekh-and-tobi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..It works for me:
https://github.com/justin-taylor/Facebook-Friends-List-for-Android

Comment: Can you please send me apk of this app? @Ronak Badjatya